# How to load images after upload them on server side and save url in mysql database

Tags: javascript, php, html, file-upload

I build this code to upload file from my web page. The scope is to move to server side the image and save the name of it on mysql database. With the follow code I m able to move to server the images uploaded and save on mysql database the information that I need. Now the problem is this: when I re-open the web page I should to display also the images previous uploaded but I m not able to do this.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        if (window.File && window.FileList && window.FileReader) {
            $("#randomImages").on("change", function(e) {
                //alert("onchange");
                var files = e.target.files,
                filesLength = files.length;
                //alert(files);
                for (var i = 0; i < filesLength; i++) {
                    var f = files[i]
                    var fileReader = new FileReader();
                    fileReader.onload = (function(e) {
                        var file = e.target;
                        $("<span class=\"pip\">" +
                            "<img class=\"imageThumb\" src=\"" + e.target.result + "\" title=\"" + file.name + "\"/>" +
                            "<br/><span class=\"remove\">Rimuovi</span>" +
                            "</span>").insertAfter("#randomImages");
                            $(".remove").click(function(){
                            $(this).parent(".pip").remove();
                        });
          
          // Old code here
          /*$("<img></img>", {
            class: "imageThumb",
            src: e.target.result,
            title: file.name + " | Click to remove"
          }).insertAfter("#files").click(function(){$(this).remove();});*/
          
                    });
                fileReader.readAsDataURL(f);
            }
        });
    } else {
        alert("Il browser corrente non supporta il caricamento immagini")
    }
    });
</script>
<style>
        input[type="file"] {
          display: block;
        }
        .imageThumb {
          max-height: 75px;
          border: 2px solid;
          padding: 1px;
          cursor: pointer;
        }
        .pip {
          display: inline-block;
          margin: 10px 10px 0 0;
        }
        .remove {
          display: block;
          background: #444;
          border: 1px solid black;
          color: white;
          text-align: center;
          cursor: pointer;
        }
        .remove:hover {
          background: white;
          color: black;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <div class="field" align="left">
          <h3>Carica le immagini</h3>
          <input type="file" id="randomImages" name="randomImages[]" multiple />
        </div>
```

I m using php as language.

Comment: What does "not able to" mean exactly? Show the code you tried for that an explain what goes wrong.

Answer (score 4):

Going a bit away from your code, let's have a look at the overall picture.
Those are the steps you have to perform:

1. Upload file on the client (Browser)
2. Send POST request to the server (your API/third party Service)
3. Store the file on disk (e.g. [Amazon S3](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/)) and store a reference to it in your database (e.g. path/to/image-somehash.jpg). Make sure that this reference is unique by using a [UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) or some other kind of hash.
4. Request image on the client (Browser)
5. Look up reference in your database
6. Return the image path to your client
7. Render image as `<img src={path} />`

There are so many moving parts that it is not possible to answer your question based on your code example but maybe you could tackle each step on it's own